# Is there an opposite for the DelayQueue?

Tags: java, queue

I would need a queue that will automatically remove elements that are older than a given amount of milliseconds - basically, I want the items in the queue to expire after some time.

I see there is a delay queue that seems to be doing the opposite: 'an element can only be taken when its delay has expired.' (I've never used it).

Maybe there is a queue implementation that does what I need? It would be better if it was bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove expired objects you need a DelayQueue and a Thread which will extract expired objects from it, something like this:

```
static class Wrapper<E> implements Delayed {
    E target;
    long exp = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000; // 5000 ms delay

    Wrapper(E target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    E get() {
        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        return unit.convert(exp - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final DelayQueue<Wrapper<Integer>> q = new DelayQueue<>();
    q.add(new Wrapper<>(1));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    q.add(new Wrapper<>(2));

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for(;;) {
                    Wrapper<Integer> w = q.take();
                    System.out.println(w.get());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly if I added more element to the queue.

q.add(new Wrapper<>(1));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    q.add(new Wrapper<>(2));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
q.add(new Wrapper<>(1));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    q.add(new Wrapper<>(2));

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is *who* and *at which point* will remove the elements that have expired. If your concern is the size of the queue not growing beyond certain limits, you will have to have a separate "cleaner" thread, removing things from your queue as they expire. You can implement it with a `DelayQueue` (`offer` would add to an internal `LinkedHashSet` and a `DelayQueue`, `poll` operates on the set, and additionally a cleaner thread polls the `DelayQueue`, and remove things from the set as they "ripen").

If you do not care all that much about items being removed from the queue as soon as they expire, you can just override the `poll` method of a standard queue, to check the expiration of the head, and, if it has expired, clear the rest of the queue and return null.

Answer (score 0):

i guess isn't a native implementation like that in java, i'm not sure through. But you can you a cache to hold this situation, not sure if is the best approuch, but you can use google guava for that, seting a Expiration Time for your itens so you'll only recover values that aren't expired.

Here are the docs for the google guava cache implementation: [Guava Doc](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Hope it helps!